# How can I filter in spark sql correctly by a date range

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a problem with my date filter.
This simple query:

```
"select `date` from dummytesttable group by `date` order by `date`"
```

has the following output:

```
StructType(List(StructField(date,DateType,true)))
[Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 14)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 15)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 16)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 17)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 18)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 19)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 20)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 21)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 22)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 23)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 24)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 25)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 26)), Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 6, 27))]
```

here you can see, that 27th is included

If I add the following condition,

```
select `date` from dummytesttable WHERE `date` between '2021-06-14' and '2021-06-27' group by `date` order by `date`
```

2021-06-27 is not included in the result.

If I change the condition to `WHERE` date `between '2021-06-14' and '2021-06-28'` it is again included.

I also tried '2021-06-27 23:59:59.999', but no luck.

If I convert the date again:

```
to_date(`date`,'yyyy-MM-dd') <= to_date('2021-06-27','yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Then 27th is included in the result.

If I do a date_format I get the following:
`date_format(CAST(date AS TIMESTAMP), yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z)='2021-06-27 00:00:00 CEST'`

How can I compare the dates correctly?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to cast the string to timestamps:

```
select `date` from dummytesttable WHERE `date` between cast('2021-06-14' as timestamp) and cast('2021-06-27' as timestamp) group by `date` order by `date`
```